# Polling from multiple SFTP host using Azure

Tags: azure-functions, sftp

This is a different circumstance than most of the Azure STFPs I've seen so far. I have followed tutorials that does the opposite.

Our need is that our clients provide us with an SFTP url, username, and password, which we must fetch  specific file from each server on a daily basis.

Is it possible to do this using Azure SFTP storage?

Do I need a program like WinSCP or something similar?

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be looking at creating Azure webjob, or daily trigger Azure function.

Comment: @Anand Sowmithiran Thank you. I will try using a time trigger function.

Comment: Scheduled WinSCP download will do too. If you have problem, please ask more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a timer trigger based `Azure function`, you can set the cron expression to run `daily`. This would be a less expensive solution.
If your source SFTP will have folders,subfolders to copy from and you don't want to write much code, then you can also use Azure `Data factory` and use the *SFTP source* [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp)